# Find specific logs about SCEP Server (unable to contact)

Tags: safari, logs, mdm

In my IT Environment, we enroll macOS systems with an MDM solution provider instance.  During the enrollment process (using the Safari Web Browser Application and using a specific Enrollment URL), the main MDM Configuration Profile (within the System Preferences Application - under the Profiles section) failed to contact and of course failed to install due to Unable to Contact SCEP Server.

Using command line or the console app, do you know if there is a way for me to retrieve the exact logs/report/error messages related to the SCEP Server failing contact?  Does Safari Application have a specific log? Does System Preferences/Profiles have a specific log?  Basically I am trying to see the actual error failing message inside the logs and hope to identify where exactly is failing, at what exact step.

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried searching console.app for the solution provider? Also it would be helpful to add the exact name of your solution provider to your original question as someone here may have experience with it.

Comment: I was going to put the name of the solution provider but I know Stack Exchange will block me if I name the provider.  Do you know what section of Console I should check? Thanks a lot Steve

Comment: Open the console.app and enter your search term in the search field, make sure "all messages" is selected. I do not believe your question will be deleted for just mentioning the system you are working with. That is done all the time. have a look, do a search on "JAMF" I show about 150 that mention that provider.

Comment: @SteveChambers thank you so much. Using console and search for SCEP keyword I was able to retrieve logs related only to SCEP and I by reading the logs I noticed that the machine (client) is failing to contact the server (which I guess) is responsible for issue the CA.  I need to find out why but again at least I know what's the issue is.  I am not sure how to close this question and give credit to you.